# create custom installer

Tags: c, windows-services, installation, windows-installer

I have created an application which is an window service which has to run under context of domain administrator account and take some server settings etc stuff.

Now I need to install it on client machine, obviously I can not do it using normal deployment project MSI because it involved custom dialog and user input while installation.

How can I do this?

Now Is there any 3rd party framework which really allow me to create custom dialog and write code which will execute at runtime?

If I have to do it manually? How I will incorporate my custom installer files and my windows server application files into a single MSI.

This is how I want to have my installation process:

1. Welcome Screen
2. System Checks
3. EULA
4. Server settings as per product licensing, its a radio selection by user.
5. Server settings based on last selection.
6. my window server settings which will make a rest call and update server.
7. accepting domain user account credentials.
8. Now installations starts.
9. Redirection to cloud portal with finish message based on selection.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is supported by MSI installers, but mostly by commercial setup tools. The server communication is usually done through built-in support or through custom actions.

Here is a list of setup tools which can get you started: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_installation_software

For example, Advanced Installer has built-in support for server-side license validation and communication.

Pick a setup tool and try to create your installer. You can then ask more specific questions if you encounter any problems.

Comment: thanks for reply. But I gone through the list and found none of them have capability to create custom dialog and code against them. I have to explore install shield and install aware. Rest all I check already.